# “you are in emergency mode,, After logging in type ”journalctl -xb“ti view…”

Tags: command-line, fstab, graphics, ram, uuid

my os (pop os , ubuntu based) gets freezed due to a RAM exceed, I reboot my system and only have CLI, were I got the tittle mentioned message:

> “you are in emergency mode,, After logging in type ”journalctl -xb“ti view…”

for getting to a solution I ran `sudo blkid` as mentioned in previous threads to see the UUIDs of the devices so I can edit certain lines in `sudo vim /etc/fstab`: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/135568/permitir-el-funcionamiento-en-modo-de-emergencia

As I understand I must change "00" to "0 0" on the correponding line on the device wwhere I mounted my os, in my case: /dev/sdb3

this is what I got when running `cat /etc/fstab`

> /etc/tab static file system information. Use 'blkid' for print
> universally unique identifier for a device; this may be used with
> UUID=  as a more robust way to name devices that works even if disks
> are added or removed. See fstab(5)
>      
> /dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap defaults 0 0
> PARTUUID=7d9d3545-8064-4caf-9c02-c8ad5d8f1f92 /boot/efi vfat
> unmask=0077 0 0  **UUID=4a53bf15-f3ba-49e6-a692-679166eab69c / ext4
> noatime,errors=rmeount-ro 0 0** UUID= 0C80015D80014EA0 /mnt/data ntfs
> defaults 0 2

*blackened highlighted line correspond to my /root system
as I see there is already a "0 0" instead of "00" on /dev/sdb3 UUID (where I have installed root system)

if it helps, I have 2 GPU drivers on my system, an NVIDIA geFORCE MX330 and a intel i7-1065G7.

so, how can I boot in normal mode ?

Comment: If you didn't modify /etc/fstab *before* the freeze, why do you believe that modifying it now is going to help? Where are the "previous threads" that suggested this?

Comment: the labove provided link appoitns to the mentioned thread: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/135568/permitir-el-funcionamiento-en-modo-de-emergencia      Now I figure out that my /mnt/data/myuser direcotry dissapeared

Comment: Were you dualbooting? I'm facing a similar issue right now and I suspect that Windows took back a hard drive that was originally allocated to it.

Comment: At that time i was not dualbooting. basically the os killed the computer lol. So at that time I extracted the SSD, made a copy of it and when I put it back to the hardware , I could boot the system in normal mode lol. Apparently it was a hardware issue (dust ?) but not totally sure. Now I'm using UBuntu 22.04 and I had experienced not problems with this ubuntu version